# Cross-Domain PostMessage communication: parent undefined

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, postmessage

Having an ugly https url on a shared hosting, I've been trying go around the javascript cross-domain restrictions using a proxy [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) and the `postMessage()` method. Sending messages from the main page to the child seems to works perfectly at first . The problems arise when I try to answer.

The source property of the `MessageEvent` is undefined, `window.parent` and `window.top` are also undefined. Therefore, I have no reference to the parent window and no way to send the result of the request.

Any help to solve the issue would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

Parent:

```js
// Never gets triggered
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) { console.log(e); });
var data = "some string";
document.getElementById("proxy_frame")
        .contentWindow.postMessage(data,"https://proxys-domain/");
```

Child:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    // This appears in chrome/ie/firefox console correctly
    console.log(message);    

    // This triggers :
    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined
    e.source.postMessage(event.currentTarget, e.origin);   
}
```

Comment: Here is a nice example of a postMessage ping pong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage - please also attach the code in question within your question.

Comment: I've been using MDN for a while, could not find any solution there. I added the code that doesn't work, it's basically the MDN example...

Comment: Here is an complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/FJ3C9/5/ please tell my if you can find your error.

Comment: Here is an example with closures: http://jsfiddle.net/FJ3C9/6/ i can not see a problem with your code. right now. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I tried on chrome, firefox and ie. Could it be due to the fact that I use two different protocols?

Comment: I'am not sure. It would be best if you could recreate the problem in a working demo. Have you tried with ssl on and off?

Comment: Well I played around with the code (there was some wrappers classes around) and it started working at one point, not sure what make it work though, I thought I had tried everything already. Well anyway, the problem reappeared later when I tried to implement the next part of the scheme: store the origin, wait for the XMLHttpRequest to return an answer and send the message.

Comment: Problem solved. It came from a stupid OOP mistake. My source was undefined because I used the wrong scope at the wrong time. Thanks for the help!